# How to print the words in a string

Tags: python, string

I want to do the following in my code:

1. Print each words of a string in a new line
2. Print each character in a new line

I have been able to achieve the second part using the following code:

```
s2 = "I am testing"
for x in s2:
    print x
```

I am having trouble achiving the first part . I have written the following code which recognizes where there is space in the string.

```
for i in s2:
    if not(i.isspace()):
        print i
    else:
        print "space"
```

Also tried the below which strips all the spaces of the string:

```
s3 = ''.join([i for i in s2 if not(i.isspace())])
print s3
```

But still not achieving my desired output, which should be something like:

```
I
am
testing
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> s2 = "I am testing"
>>> for word in s2.split():
        print(word)

    
I
am
testing
```

Comment: In case the OP is wondering why this is the answer: `split()` takes an optional argument `sep` that is used to decide how to split the string up. Wherever `sep` appears, we split the string. The key is that `sep` defaults to matching any amount of consecutive white space. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
s2 = "I am testing"
for x in s2.split():
    print(x)
```